# Order confirmation email with html content?

Tags: commerce, emails

I'm using [drupal commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) with its submodules and need to change order's confirmation message to html format and add line items and customer profile. How can I organize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Commerce Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_message). It's the best supported way to handle sending emails. It includes several message types out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

If HTML emails are a requirement, check out the [Commerce Invoice Receipt](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_invoice_receipt) module. Here's an excerpt from the project page:

> Provides an additional 'Invoice' display for Commerce orders, as well as a Rules action to email this invoice out to customers.
>   The HTML email can be customised through template files.